# Webhook event for Facebook sponsored message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook's Marketing API to create sponsored message as described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/messenger/#sponsored

After creating the ad, Facebook reviews the ad and then after approval ad gets sent to page audience. I want to know when my ad gets approved or rejected through webhook. Is it possible? Is there a way to receive webhook events for this?

Comment: I don’t think there are _any_ webhooks in the Marketing API - those are a Graph API and Messenger API thing.

Answer (score -1):

There are some ad account related webhooks in Graph API. These will send events when your ad:

1. is in_process status
2. goes out of in_process status
3. has some issues with it

Please read up more on the official documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/ad-account/